# PHP, How to get the name of the running function?

Tags: php

I'm using an error log function and I want to include the function where the error occurred during the error log. Is there a way to write the function instead of writing the function every time?

```
<?php 

$a = null;

exampleFunction($a);

function exampleFunction($variable){

  if(is_null($variable)){

    errorLog("variable is null. Function : exampleFunction()");

  }

}

function errorLog($text){

 error_log($text, 3, ".testLog");

}

?>
```

`__FUNCTION__` is not solution. If I use `__FUNCTION__` I get "errorLog". I want to know the name of the function that is running errorLog.

For example ;

```
function errorLog($text){

  error_log($text.' Function : '.$functionName, 3, ".testLog");

}
```

Comment: Try `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: As in the linked answer: in your errorLog function you could reference: `debug_backtrace()[1]['function']`.

Comment: I missed it. This solution worked. Thank you so much.  @Progrock

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `__FUNCTION__` constant. It's _ _ (2 underscores) "function" _ _ (2 underscores)

```
function whatever($stuff){
echo "The function name is " . __FUNCTION__;
}
```

If you want to take it a step further, if it's in a class...

```
echo "The class name is " . __CLASS__ . " and the function is " . __FUNCTION__;
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can use the [magic constant](https://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) __FUNCTION__

Comment: lol. Writing the double underscore in here is tricky. They turn the text in bold if they are not escaped.

Comment: You can also use the code tag to make the \_\_UNDERSCORES\_\_ not cause a bold text.